# np.around and np.round not actually rounding

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, rounding

I'm writing a simple code in `Python 2.7` to change a couple very long files i have into text files so that I can scroll through them in a text reader.

However, i found out that the `numpy.array` in the file has very long floats that end in unneeded scientific notation. I try and use `numpy.around` or `numpy.round` to change these to only have two places after the decimal but it doesn't change anything. Here is my code:

```
import h5py
import sys
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np

sys.stdout.write( 'Please pick file from window\n')
fileName = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
sys.stdout.write(fileName)
f = h5py.File(fileName, 'r')
dataset = f['/dcoor'][:]


newname = raw_input('New file name ')
print type(dataset[0][0])
dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
dataset = dataset.astype(float)
print type(dataset[0][0])
print '\nDataset before rounding: \n', dataset
dataset = np.around(dataset, decimals = 2)
print '\nDataset after rounding: \n', dataset
np.savetxt(newname,dataset)
```

I do not get any error messages and my output is this:

```
New file name test4
<type 'numpy.float32'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>

Dataset before rounding: 
[[  1.48999996e+01   1.07949997e+02   1.80000007e-01   3.59000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.60100002e+01   1.07489998e+02   3.89999986e-01   3.98000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.86700001e+01   1.07669998e+02   5.89999974e-01   4.26000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 ..., 
 [  2.78700008e+01   2.75200005e+01   2.99973999e+03   4.15000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.60499992e+01   2.72800007e+01   2.99991992e+03   4.10000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.56599998e+01   2.85400009e+01   3.00009009e+03   4.37500000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]]

Dataset after rounding: 
[[  1.49000000e+01   1.07950000e+02   1.80000000e-01   3.59000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.60100000e+01   1.07490000e+02   3.90000000e-01   3.98000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.86700000e+01   1.07670000e+02   5.90000000e-01   4.26000000e+02
    0.00000000e+00]
```

Which is odd since it appears to round some numbers but not others, and keeps the trailing `zeros` as well. i converted the original `array` because i thought that might make a difference but obviously it did not. Could the problem be that the `array`'s are so long? Each one is roughly 16,000 rows. Could it be that the original `array` was saved in an `hdf5` file which keeps the original format? I can't go back and retest my mice i work with so if that's the case i'm rather `SOL`. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers *are* being rounded. The reason why they aren't *precisely* two decimal places is because IEEE 754 floating point numbers have rounding errors. Since you can't represent all floating point numbers perfectly (with a limited size) in any given base (base 2 in this case), there are implicit precision problems.

Think about numbers like `2/3` or `5/7`. You can't perfectly represent them in base 10.

However, I'm not sure why you care about the fact that the way that Numpy visually represents floats with `repr` uses scientific notation. When you want to write them out you can use loop over the array and specify the precision **when writing**:

```
for row in dataset:
    for elem in row:
        somefile.write("%.2f" % (elem,))
```

This will ensure that only 2 decimal places are written (and it will round it in the way that you're trying to). But it's important to note that when you load the files, it will still have the same IEEE 754 drawbacks.